# Bellman's equation for Markov Decision Process

Tags: probability-theory, machine-learning, markov-process

I've been watching Reinforced learning lectures by David Silver.  In the second lectures at 32:19 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfHX2hHRMVQ he mentions Bellman's equation for Markov Decision Process, which is the following: 
$v(s) = \mathbb{E}(R_{t+1} + \gamma v(S_{t+1})|S_{t}=s ) $. It is said that it can be derived from "the law of iterated expectations" which states that $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|Y)) = \mathbb{E}(X)$. Frankly I don't see how these two are connected. In the case of Bellman's equation we would like to show that $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(R_{t+2} +....|S_{t+1})|{S_t}) = \mathbb{E}(R_{t+2} +...|S_t) $ and I feel that we need to assume some additional properties of $R_{n}$ but none were given. How can one prove this equality?

Answer (score 0):

Law of iterated expectations is a powerful result in probability theory and it does not depend on $R_n$ at all. If you view conditional expectation as some form of projection, then what law of iterated expectation tells you is that if one space contains the other, then it does not really matter what order you project the variables onto these spaces, and you will be exactly at the same place as if you had projected initially to the smaller subspace.

I don't know how technical of a proof you want, but there is a proof in Durrett's Probability Theory & Examples (PTE) in Chapter 5. This requires some measure theory though, and I am not sure how you can write a formal proof without some measure theory.

(If you don't know any measure theory, this intuition might be more helpful: My best estimate for $R_i$ given $S_{i+1}$ is some random quantity, and if I average that over what I know according to $S_i$, I basically am still getting the best estimate as if I had just been given $S_i$.)

Comment: So what does this law state? From the first paragraph of your answer I deduce that it is the equality $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|F)|G) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|G)|F)=\mathbb{E}(X|F) $ if $F \subset G $. How does this help in my example since we don't know that $\sigma(S_t) \subset \sigma(S_{t+1})$?

Comment: Yeah, that is the equality. I just assumed (did not watch the video yet) he was talking about $S_t$ and $S_{t+1}$ were defined as the sigma algebra generated by a process from time 0 to time t; let me have a look at the video.

Comment: I think you can add $S_t = s$ to the inner conditioning, since conditioned on $S_{t+1}$, $G_{t+1}$ and $S_t = s$ are independent (then you can use this law); I am not sure about this adding to inner conditioning part though; I haven't seen this proof in PTE.

Comment: I just need to calculate $\mathbb{E}(R_{t+2} \cdot 1_{S_{t+1}=s'} \cdot 1_{S_{t}=s}) $ in terms of $p_{s,s'}$ and $ \mathbb{E}(R_{t+2}|S_{t+1}=s')=r_{s'}$ (the assumption is that $r_s$ does not depend on time). Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I think it is just the product of those two quantities (if I did the math right)
$\frac{E[R_{t+2} 1_{S_{t+1} = s'} 1_{S_t = s}]}{P(S_{t+1} = s')}$
=$E[R_{t+2}1_{S_t = s} \mid S_{t+1} = s' ]$
=$E[R_{t+2} \mid S_{t+1} = s' ]E[1_{S_t = s} \mid S_{t+1} = s' ]$
=$r_{s'} \frac{p_{s,s'}}{P(S_{t+1} = s')}$; now cancel the $P(S_{t+1} = s')$ from both sides.

Comment: Conditioning involving probabilities and events comes from another Durrett book: Essentials of Stochastic Processes (EoSP); again chapter 5. Also, you probably noticed that I am making an independence assumption; your immediate reward depends only on your current state, right? (Also, this is some form of a Markov process right? If I tell you might state right now, all states before now are irrelevant right?)